# Is it possible to project a vector on another vector to calculate the distance without raycasting

Tags: unity, mathematics, vector

I have the following game scenario:

Player is P and there are 2 enemies E1 and E2

[image]

I want to calculate the distance between the ennemies and **the player base** which is anywhere in that green line, and not the actual player character.

Currently if if I try to calculate the distance between enemies and players I get something like this:

[image]

But what i really want is this:

[image]

Now i could've just raycast from the enemies forward to hit the "base collider" but this is what am trying to avoid.

My question is:

If the green line is always going to be a "longer version" of the player Transform.Right vector, is there a way to project the Enemies Transform.forward vector, and now where it intersects with the player vector like this:

[image]

If you're curious about the reason behind this, then this image should clarify it:

[image]

Basically I need to create a "high threat zone" in front of the player, and based on the enemy distance to the "player base", i will give different feedback.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to define which line your base is on, not at a certain point. But if this line is sure to be on the x-axis, you can simply use the difference of Y.

Comment: that's the problem, the player is not always facing the same direction, sometimes the Y difference works perfectly fine, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with **[Vector3.Project](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Project.html)()**

So basically what i needed to do is to project the enemies normal (in this case the forward) on the distance vector.

And then use the projection result's magnitude to determine the distance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: pic]

1. Defines the face direction(vfront) of the base.
2. v1 = e1 - p; v2= e2 - p
3. Obtain the dot product of v1 and v2 to vfront. If the result < 0, the point is behind the "line".

[Dot Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

Comment: thanks, but the goal is not to JUST know if the point has crossed the line or not, but to also know how far is it from the the line (perpendicularly), I already solved the problem though, check out my answer in this thread if you're curious.